# TypeError: 'directoryClass' object is not subscriptable, tried de-subscripting it base on syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

This code gives me an error saying `TypeError: 'directoryClass' object is not subscriptable`

```
class directoryClass(): # Here we create the directory class in which we can create an object
                        # to define a directory in which we may encase files.
   Child = {}
   Parent = ''
   Referance = ''

my_picObject = directoryClass()
my_docObject = directoryClass()
userObject = directoryClass()
usersObject = directoryObject()

def my_picObj():
   my_picObject = directoryClass()
   my_picObject.Child = {'"Hello World.py"' : {'DataType' : 'Read', 'Information' : 'World'}}
   my_picObject.Parent = userObject
   my_picObject.Referance = 'My Pictures'

def my_docObj():
    my_docObject = directoryClass()
    my_docObject.Child = {'Input.py' : {'DataType' : 'Read', 'Information' : 'Hello World'}}
    my_docObject.Parent = userObject
    my_docObject.Reference = 'My Documents'

def userObj():
    userObject = directoryClass()
    userObject.Child = {'"My Documents"' : my_docObject, '"My Pictures"' : my_picObject}
    userObject.Parent = usersObject
    userObject.Referance = 'User'

def usersObj():
    usersObject = directoryClass()
    usersObject.Child = {'User' : userObject}
    usersObject.Parent = 'None'
    usersObject.Referance = 'Users'

my_picObj()
my_docObj()
userObj()
usersObj()

print = usersObject.Child['User']['"My Pictures"']['"Hello World.py"']['Information'] #Error Occurs here

print(print)
```

Ignor this text it is to make more text than code in this....
Ignor this text it is to make more text than code in this....
Ignor this text it is to make more text than code in this....
Ignor this text it is to make more text than code in this....

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Why do you use function names as global variable names? Why are **all** variables global including the supposed class members? This code in incomprehensible to me.

Comment: Please explain what it is supposed to archive.

Comment: It is basicly a fake directory tree. say that print was a command I typed in I want it to exacute that from the my_picObject.Child['"Hello World.py"'][Information]

Comment: The functions arn't ment to be global, the objects are. The functions are named like the objects.

Comment: I just noticed you are still young and probably rather new to programming. Do you have some beginner's book to learning python? If not I would highly suggest getting one. Short tutorials often don't explain the basic principles well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usersObject = directoryClass()
usersObject.Child = {'User' : userObject}
```

After these two lines `usersObject.Child['User']` references `userObject`, which itself is of type `directoryClass`:

```
userObject = directoryClass()
```

Since `directoryClass` has no subscription operator, you cannot index it.

Several general points towards your code:

1. Don't use the same name for a function and a variable
2. Class members are set in an `__init__` method and are never `global`:

   ```
   class directoryClass():
       def __init__(self):
           self.Child = {}
           self.Parent = ''
           self.Referance = ''
   ```
3. You don't need to declare objects defined in the global scope as `global`, so `global directoryClass` is redundant.
4. Functions are supposed to return whatever they created (for the most part), not set global variables. SO do it like this:

   ```
   def my_picObject():
       my_picObject_obj = directoryClass() # Notice different name and not global
       my_picObject_obj.Child = {'"Hello World.py"' : {'DataType' : 'Read', 'Information' : print('Hello World...'), 'Size' : 8}}
       my_picObject_obj.Parent = userObject
       my_picObject_obj.Referance = 'My Pictures'
       return my_picObject_obj
   ```

   If you do it like this, then you can call other functions to get their constructed object:

   ```
    def my_picObject():
       my_picObject_obj = directoryClass()
       my_picObject_obj.Child = {'"Hello World.py"' : {'DataType' : 'Read', 'Information' : print('Hello World...'), 'Size' : 8}}
       my_picObject_obj.Parent = userObject() # Assign the returned values of userObject()
       my_picObject_obj.Referance = 'My Pictures'
       return my_picObject_obj
   ```

   Then the block

   ```
   my_picObject()
   my_docObject()
   userObject()
   usersObject()
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   usersObject_obj = usersObject()
   ```

   because all other calls are made recursive.
5. You cannot assign python commands to variables like this:

   ```
    my_docObject.Child = {'Input.py' : {'DataType' : 'Read', 'Information' : print('input = input()')}}
   ```

   I don't know what exactly you are trying to do here. So I cannot really help as long as you haven't clarified.
6. Don't assign to `print`, that is dangerous, call it instead:

   ```
   print(usersObject.Child['User']['"My Pictures"']['"Hello World.py"']['Information'])
   ```
7. Also

   ```
    usersObject.Child['User']['"My Pictures"']['"Hello World.py"']['Information']
   ```

   should be something like

   ```
    usersObject.Child['User'].Child['"My Pictures"'].Child['"Hello World.py"'].Child['Information']
   ```

   because each level of the structure is of type `directoryClass` and contains a directory named `Child` which you may index.

Comment: @TheMountainFurnaceGabriel I guess not, I added a relevant point to the list that might help. As the code stands it's hard for me to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: So if I fixed the assigning python command and fixed assigning print and changed the names(new edited code), what else would I do? I have tried creating each object a different type of class with the same variables.

Comment: Actuly, I read over your answer again, and it works now with some tweaks. Thanks